# php artisan serve on windows not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, git-bash

I'm trying to run this command on my windows with `git bash`:

```
php artisan serve --host=0
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: geta
> ddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in Unknown on line 0 [Wed Mar
> 15 18:02:32 2017] Failed to listen on 0:8000 (reason:
> php_network_getad dresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
> ) <br /> <b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses:
> getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in <b>Unknown</b> on line
> <b>0</b><br /> error

and suggestion?
```

Comment: Well, `0` is not a valid host. You should use `localhost` for example. The error is explicit, the host `0` does not exist.

Comment: tnx..on mac its working with 0 but on window its not..with localhost is working

Comment: I guess there's a redirection on mac from 0 to localhost maybe. That said, you don't even need to specify the host.

Comment: MacOS may support entering IP Addresses in plain decimal form rather than the traditional [dotted quad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation?oldformat=true). Windows, however, only accepts the address in the traditional notation.

Comment: I'm trying to use `--host=forum.localhost.com` to test a subdomain in development mode, but it doesn't work.